# Curl POST upload file request returns false

Tags: php, curl, post, php-curl

I'm trying to use the gfycat API to create a gfycat with a file upload through curl with php but it doesn't work and var_dump($response) gives me bool(false).

**My Code:**

```
$file_path = $target_dir.$newfilename;
$cFile = curl_file_create($file_path);
$data = array(
     "file" => $cFile,
);
$target_url = "https://filedrop.gfycat.com";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
));            

$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response); // bool(false) here

curl_close($ch);
```

Help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What will be displayed if you add `if (curl_errno($ch)) { echo 'Request error:' . curl_error($ch); } else { var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch)); }` after `curl_exec($ch)` but before `curl_close($ch)` ?

Comment: @camelsWriteInCamelCase Nothing, just the Request error: from the echo, but curl_error($ch) seems to be empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Btw I got it to work with this:

```
$file_path = "ABSOLUTE_FILE_PATH".$newfilename;
$cFile = curl_file_create(realpath($file_path));
$data = array(
"key" => $newfilename,
"file" => $cFile,
);
$target_url = "https://filedrop.gfycat.com";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
"Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

when debugging curl code, it's often a good idea to enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE and check the stderr log. further more, if curl_exec reutrned bool(false), it means there was a problem with the transfer, and you can use the curl_error() function to get an error message. and lastly, don't set the header `"Content-Type: multipart/form-data"` manually, curl will set that header for you, and unlike you, curl won't make any typos in doing so, and worse, you risk overwriting/removing the boundary parameter of the header.

try

```
$file_path = $target_dir . $newfilename;
$cFile = curl_file_create ( $file_path );
$data = array (
        "file" => $cFile 
);
$target_url = "https://filedrop.gfycat.com";

$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST" );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
try {
    $stderrh = tmpfile ();
    curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
            CURLOPT_STDERR => $stderrh 
    ) );
    $response = curl_exec ( $ch );
    if ($response === false) {
        throw new \RuntimeException ( "curl error " . curl_errno ( $ch ) . ": " . curl_error ( $ch ) . " - verbose log: " . file_get_contents ( stream_get_meta_data ( $stderrh ) ['uri'] ) ); // https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268
    }
} finally{
    curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 0,
            CURLOPT_STDERR => STDERR 
    ) );
    fclose ( $stderrh );
}
var_dump ( $response ); // bool(false) here
curl_close ( $ch );
```

now, if there is an error, it should give you a nice detailed log of what happened up to to the curl error, in the exception error log.